# Android drawable xxx-hdpi

Tags: android

i m trying to find a solution to this error:

C:\Users\Rami Babay\AndroidStudioProjects\Maps\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxdhpi

Error:Error: Invalid resource directory name

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\Rami Babay\AndroidStudioProjects\Maps\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxdhpi: Error: Invalid resource directory name

Answer (score 2):

The directory should be named

```
drawable-xxxhdpi
```

You have a typo there.

Comment: im trying to create the directory xxx-hdpi it says it exist already

Comment: Well, then it exists already and you have to move the content of drawable-xxxdhpi to drawable-xxxhdpi.